# Plot a horizontal line in chartSeries Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to create a time-series plot for Goldman adjusted stock price since 2000 and draw a horizontal line for the mean price. However, I reached "Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device" error message when I tried to draw the horizontal line.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GS", from = "2000-01-01", src="yahoo")
chart_Series(GS[,6], name = "Goldman Sachs", TA = 'addLines(h = mean(GS[,6]))')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing codes from 2 different charting options. You have `chartSeries` in quantmod and `chart_Series`. A bit confusing as the second version tends to have to nicer charts, but is not complete like `chartSeries`. There is no `add_Lines` function for `chart_Series`. But there are workarounds.

**Simple solution, use `chartSeries`:**

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GS", from = "2000-01-01", src="yahoo")
chartSeries(GS[,6], name = "Goldman Sachs", TA = 'addLines(h = mean(GS[,6]))')
```

**Bit more complicated using `chart_Series`:**

You need to use add_TA, which needs a xts object so first you need to create an xts object with the same value. Those are the first 3 lines of code below. Next you plot the data and then you use add_TA to add the horizontal line. And you need to tell add_TA where to plot the line (on = 1 means main plot window).

```
dates <- index(GS)
gs_mean <- mean(GS[,6])
gs_mean_xts <- xts(rep(gs_mean, length(dates)), dates)

# create chart
chart_Series(GS[,6], name = "Goldman Sachs")

# plot horizontal line on plot
add_TA(gs_mean_xts, on = 1, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```